# Add character "/" at the end of link

Tags: .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble writing files **.htaccess**

**For example:** My site is: **www.namesite.com** and have the following url:

> www.namesite.com/cat/
>
> www.namesite.com/cat/cat-white.html
>
> www.namesite.com/cat/cat-black.html

I want that when a user tried to uncheck "/" at the end of link

> www.namesite.com/cat/ => www.namesite.com/cat

is now automatically add a **"/"** at the end of link

> => www.namesite.com/cat/

looking forward to the help of everyone. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can have this rule for adding trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have actually tested it before posting. FOr which URL it didn't work? Make sure this is first rule in you .htaccess and there is no other conflicting .htaccess.

Comment: thanks.  it working when I removed some line in file .htaccess ^3^